# php загрузка файла с пометкой

Tags: php

Возможно ли сделать загрузку файла с пометкой (к примеру пользователь качает txt файл а в самом низу его буде пометка по типу "Данный файл был скачен с сайта.." ну и в том духе)
Код php который пока что используется:

```
<?php
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/files/textfile.txt'; //полный путь к нашему файлу 
if(!file_exists($file)) {echo "not_file!";} else { //проверим существует ли файл
//Заголовки ответа на запрос, что отвечаем мы потоком байт
header ("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header ('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header ("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
header ('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header ("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($file));  
//Передаем наш файл в ответ на запрос
readfile($file.);
}
?>
```

[image: Пример того как должно выглядеть после]

Comment: после `readfile($file.);` добавьте `echo 'Данный файл бла-бла-бла';`

Comment: @ArchDemon content-length надо изменить еще. но собственно это прокатит только для тхт файлов, очевидно.

Comment: @teran, я бы вообще убрал этот заголовок. Может и не совсем правильно, но работать будет и так.

Answer (score -1):

Здесь с архивацией, выпилить если что несложно

```
$destFile = $filename.'.zip';
$sourceFile = $filename.'.txt';
$password = 'dsfsdfdfs';

$fp = fopen($sourceFile, "w");
fwrite($fp, "новая строка\r\n\r\n");
fclose ($fp);
$cmd = "`which zip` -j -P {$password} {$destFile} {$sourceFile}";
exec($cmd);
unlink($sourceFile);
```